# How to retrieve domain name from salesforce org

Tags: mydomain

`Select id,Domain from domain`

This query does not return any records. I am trying to retrieve domain name in my salesforce org so that i can append it to  that to any new user's username in salesforce at the time of  creation.

Did anybody face this issue and if so , how did you overcome this?

Thanks,
Asha

Answer (score 4):

Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl will return your "my domain" URL (e.g. https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/), and you can get the Host from here:

```
String myDomain = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
```

The [Domain](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_domain.htm) object is related to Site.com, which is not your intent.